# ssrs reporting services column under column

Tags: reporting-services

ssrs reporting services column under column
I don't know how do it. Is it possible in matrix  on the picture?

[image]

Comment: Please Clarify your question, it is not clear on what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make a second tablix and put it under the first one.  If you make the columns in the second tablix all the same width as the columns in the first, it will line up like your picture.